# Recording gameobject with hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

In unity editor, I'm using the UnityEditor.Experimental.Animations.GameObjectRecorder to record an animation of a gameobject.
Is it possible to do something like that with hololens?
If no, do you know how can I record the behavior of a gameobject in the space? such as transform, materials etc ?

Comment: Probably not. The animation recorder is just an easy way of changing a GO's properties and having them show up as keyframes in an intuitive way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work with your problem, but here's what I did for one of my projects.

We wanted to be able to manipulate an object while using hololens and record how we moved this object, so we could play it again on the hololens. I used List of Vector3 elements and was recording the starting position before the movement, and the end position (those positions were added to a list on `OnManipulationStarted` and `OnManipulationCompleted`. You could also save more positions if you wanted to by saving them from `OnManipulationUpdated`). Once I had those two positions I was able to find linear interpolation between them using Vector3.Lerp, which I was calling within a Coroutine.

Hope this helps if you're still looking for a solution.

Comment: Well, I'm saving in a txt file all the data about the objects, and then read the file and change the attributes... Similar to your solution